# Pseudo element on div and span

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand why the "before is here" is showing on every span of my div. I think missing something to understand the :before behaviour.
It would be great if someone could clarify why the "before is here" is not shown only once and is applied on every span.

```css
#test :before {
  content:"before is here ";
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to remove the space, otherwise the selector is equivalent to `#test *:before` (_the :before of each element inside #text_)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Thanks for the tip. It does the trick. I think it is confusing though that a space can lead to a  different behaviour.

Comment: it is not a trick, it is the intended behaviour: when you insert spaces inside a selector you're actually describing and targeting one or more subtrees of your DOM hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space makes a difference. When you put `#test :before`, it implies:

```css
#test *::before
```

The above means the `::before` pseudo element of all the containing ones.

And without the space: `#test:before`, it implies:

```css
#test::before
```

This will affect only the `#test`, which is what you are looking for. See both the snippets, that use with and without space:

```css
#test :before {
  content:"before is here ";
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
</div>
```

**Without Space**

```css
#test:before {
  content:"before is here ";
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
</div>
```

Hope you understood.

Answer (score 0):

The *pseudo-elements* `::before` and `::after` are indicated with the following syntax: a **double-colon**, directly following the element / id / class in question.

> [CSS3 pseudo-element double colon syntax (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Advanced_CSS_selectors#CSS3_pseudo-element_double_colon_syntax)

The double-colon distinguishes *pseudo-elements* from *pseudo-classes* like `:hover` and `:target`, which have are indicated by a single colon.

Thus, your style declaration should read:

```
#test::before {
  content: 'before is here ';
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`:before` isn't the same as `::before`.

`#test :before` applies the following CSS to every child of the `#test element`, where as `#test::before` applies the CSS to the element itself.

```
#test::before {
  content:"before is here ";
  color:red;
}
```

works the way you want it to.